# Image won't load in Flask App static folder

Tags: html, flask

I am trying to add an image to the header of my app and it will not load.  I have the image stored in the static folder which is at the same level as the app.py file. The code that should display the image is:

```
<header class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
  <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='marco_icon.png')}}" />
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

when I open the app it appears as an error icon:
[image]

When I inspect the element it shows:
[image]

app.py code is as follows:

```
from myproject import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**init**.py is as follows:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app,db)

from myproject.trips.views import trips_blueprint

app.register_blueprint(trips_blueprint,url_prefix='/trips')
```

Directory structure:

[image]

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to show us your Python code

Comment: yea, that code seems to be appropriate, without more information i probably can't help you

Comment: what python code do I need to send? my app.py file or __init__.py file?

Comment: Publish both as it depends where you put the app creation.

Comment: just added it to the original question, thanks.

Comment: OK, last thing in order to be able to help you. We need to know your directory structure. On Linux you could use `tree`.

Comment: I added that above as well. templates is lower case in reality... small typo

Comment: Usually the templates and the static folders are found at the same level in a Flask application, even when using blueprints. So the fix could be as simple as moving the static folder under myproject.